# Defining model properties in typo3

Tags: php, typo3

I'm learning typo3. I have my own Idea model, and this ideas have one and just one category. So my ideas table has a category column with the id of the core system categories from typo3. I understand that in order to set that category property correctly I have to do something the following code. But I don't know what does this mean or how to use ObjectStorage. Any documentation about ObectStorage will be well received.

What does it mean what's between <>? What type of variable is then? ObjectStorage or Category?

```
/**
 * The category of the idea
 *
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\Category>
 */
protected $category;
```

Comment: The class name between the `<>` tells Extbase which types of objects will be in the `ObjectStorage` - it is conceptually like a typed array. The type of `$category` is still an object of type `ObjectStorage`. This needs to match a column TCA definition in order to be functional.
Some of the information (e.g. https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/5-Domain/2-implementing-the-domain-model.html) is helpful but might not directly answer your questions. I'd like to invite you to the TYPO3 slack https://typo3.org/community/meet/chat-slack

Comment: Ey! Thanks! I'm not sure that it matches my TCA definition, I'm gonna check it out. And try to join slack chat, I need guidance with this, it's hard.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want in principle:

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Categories/Index.html

In your TCA for "ideas" just limit "category" to max. 1